# Selenium: What to do for those elements whose XPath is not static?

Tags: selenium, xpath, netsuite

Each and every time I am searching for an Xpath of some inner menu element in NetSuite, the ID keeps on changing and I cannot fetch something which will be static and usable.

Comment: Perhaps you need to construct _Dynamic XPath_

Comment: Perhaps you need a more flexible XPath. Hard to say any more than that if you don't give us the slightest idea what your HTML/XML looks like.

Comment: Could you share the html of the element in 2 different cases?

Comment: I. //*[@id="nl37"]/a/span

II. //*[@id="nl9"]/a/span

Then I used Mozilla Firefox and got this path:

/html/body/div[6]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/a/span

But we can't use this one as if any other element gets added to the page, then the xpath gets changed too.

How to fetch a relative xpath...

Answer (score 0):

The second XPath looks for me like you copied it? My first advice is not to use XPaths starting with "/html". (very static because of starting on HTML tag!)

The other xPath also works on Firefox with an unchanged web page. //*[@id="nl9"]/a/span

Let me explain you how the concept is:

The * means that you search the id attribute with value "19" on any tag. The star is a Joker for the tag name. Then you go into the span tag under the a-tag.

Another hint to check XPaths:

If you would like to check your XPath open the console tab in the developer tools of your browser (where you can copy xpaths), type: `$x("<your xpath>")` and ENTER. If you get a tree instead of an error your xpath is valid.

By clicking through the tree structure you got, the element the xpath belongs to will be marked.

For understanding xpath Syntax better, take a look at:

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp

Hope this helps :)

Comment: xpath starting with `//*` should be as avoided as absolute xpath, especially since OP refences a specific ID. Furthermore: if `a` is under that ID, why not search for that `a` element directly? links are rarely duplicate each other completely, and often are the best thing to search for

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Looking for the link might be the best approach.